# No option to Shutdown when running from Live CD

Tags: live-cd, ubiquity

After installation it asks me to restart or continue using live system and im going to use live system but afer wards i can't shut down my computer there is only restart or hibernate available. I think it is a designing fault.

Comment: this is not a question.

Comment: You may need to file this as a bug report.

Comment: I get the same thing.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi It *might* be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/661250).

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal and type `sudo shutdown -s` then press enter.

*Next time please ask a question and not write a rant :).*

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl + Alt + Delete` if you can't find the reboot or shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and...

for shutdown - type:

```
sudo halt
```

for restart - type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: For shutdown, why not `sudo poweroff`?

Comment: Cuz in 2011 `sudo poweroff` did not work yet? :) `sudo halt` is wrong nowadays: it is no longer possible to map `halt` to `poweroff` from `/etc/default/halt` without killing `halt` itself.